# What's the best time to start holiday shopping this year?

Tags: shopping, online-shopping, product-coupons

I am planning and making a list of things I need to buy this Christmas. Can you please tell me the best time to start holiday shopping so I can benefit from best deals online for electronics and etc.

I am a savvy shopper and always check online coupons and deals before making any purchase. I also subscribe to [Coupon Park](http://www.couponpark.com/) and [Retail Me Not](http://www.retailmenot.com/)’s weekly newsletters so I can never miss a great deal and coupon. Is this enough or I am missing something?

What other saving tips or online sources you think I need to consider so I can plan my holiday shopping and save money.

Comment: 26th December 2013!

Comment: The sooner the better the less days you have to shop, is the less days you have to shop.

Comment: Attention close votes:   this question is "Strategies for saving more money" and on-topic per the site help.

Comment: It would help to know what country you are in.

Comment: in United States.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you're shopping for.  Black Friday and Cyber Monday deals are often very good for some things and mediocre to downright bad for other things.  I recommend trying to figure out what things you want to buy now, and tracking the price for 4-8 weeks.  That will help give you a better price anchor to know when a deal is "good" vs. "not good".

Answer (score 2):

The best time to start holiday shopping is just after the holidays, when stores are selling off their remaining overstock. Outside of that, there's no one answer.

Comment: I think this is incorrect.  There are certainly seasons to buy things:  http://lifehacker.com/5973864/the-best-time-to-buy-anything-during-the-year is an example of such a resource.

Comment: I didn't say there wasn't an answer -- just that there wasn't a _single_ answer other than post-holiday inventory reduction. (And frankly I'm skeptical about the rest; those are manufactured shopping seasons.)

Comment: But there are ways and strategies that can be outlined.

Comment: So it is claimed. I'm less than convinced.

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you need to make a list of things you need to shop and make a list of websites which are offering good deals for the items you want to purchase. You can use vouchers collected from previous purchases. Call the sellers for the listed items and see if you can negotiate a better deal. The reason you need to do this - you may not get great deals for the items you intend to purchase during or after Christmas/Boxing day/New year/. My answer start looking out from today.